# PHP Why does the PHP code return the number of rows twice?

Tags: php

Why does this code return the number of rows twice?

```
<?php
    include("dbinfo.php");
    $link = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password);
    if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $link);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM apptable");
    $no = mysql_num_rows($result);
    mysql_close($link);
        echo "<h1><big>".$no."</big></h1>";
?>
```

Also, can someone access dbinfo.php somehow and get to the password?

Sorry, I'm using the following code to display this output, but it shows the number of rows twice, once with formatting and the other without.

```
<td>
      <?php include("regcount.php"); echo $no; ?>
      </td>
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Is this all the code? How are you invoking it?

Comment: can you describe what you expect to see vs. what you're actually seeing?

Comment: which file is regcount.php, and where is $no come from?

Comment: 0_0  "Also, can someone access dbinfo.php somehow and get to the password?"  Are you asking us to hack your server?

Comment: @JackManey Pretty sure he's asking if an attacker can access his dbinfo.php file.

Comment: @jack-maney Nope, I was kind of confused, I though there was something like the last variable in script being echoed so I thought that it automatically makes all of my scripts vulnerable!

Comment: For the down-voters, I did research this! But its better to be safe than sorry, the 2 echoes were very scary!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're including the file (which echos it) then you're echoing it again.

```
include("regcount.php"); // This will output everything in regcount.php, including formatted count
echo $no; // Then you're echoing the variable that holds the result of mysql_num_rows()
```

Comment: So the include part automatically echoes it, right? also, just want to ask, there's no such thing as the last variable in the script being echoed, is there?

Comment: Yes, including something is virtually the same thing as opening that file, copying/pasting the contents into the including file. I don't know what you mean by "last variable in the script being echoed".

Comment: @AdeelHasanAkbari, no the last variable in the script is not echoed. Only text outside of `<?php ... ?>` tags and the output of explicit `echo` or other output functions are included in the output.

Answer (score 3):

It's echoing `$no` twice because you're telling it to

```
echo "<h1><big>".$no."</big></h1>";
<?php include("regcount.php"); echo $no; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two points where you do an `echo $no`, so `$no` is echoed twice, once in the included `regcount.php`, and once in the original file.

As for `dbinfo.php`, the only way someone could see it is if your server is misconfigured. As a general rule, it's a good idea to keep any sensitive information like that outside of the webserver's document path and include it by using a relative (as in `include("../dbinfo.php")`) or absolute path (as in `include("/some/path/dbinfo.php")`.

You could also use [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to add the path where your `dbinfo.php` files lives:

```
$path = '/some/path/';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
include("dbinfo.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's examine what's going on here:

```
<?php include("regcount.php"); echo $no; ?>
```

This includes and executes `regcount.php`, which does an `echo()` call to display the number of rows, formatted. Then it prints out the value of `$no`, which is why you're getting the number twice, once with formatting (from `regcount.php`) and once without (from `$no`).

As for your other question about `dbinfo.php`, if all you're doing is setting variables, then no, the user can't see your password. If it's echoing anything, then it'll display that. It's really impossible to say without seeing what `dbinfo.php` has in it.

Comment: No echoes there - Thanks for the info!